# How to delete tags from references ( cq:tags ) on removing it from tagging list?

Tags: javascript, aem

When i`m deleting tags from tagging section in cq5/AEM, The same tags are m=not being removed from page references ( cq:tags ) section.

So far i`m succeeded in finding the paths the tags are being referred to. But unable to delete that tags from ( cq:tags ) section. Can anyone help me.

I`m trying to achieve it in scripting

```
(function () {
if (window.location.pathname !== "/tagging") {
    return;
}

registerShowRefsAlert();

//the query to find tag references (pages and assets)
var CHECK_TAGS_SQL_2_QUERY = "SELECT * from [nt:base] AS t WHERE NAME(t) = 'jcr:content' " +
                                "AND CONTAINS(t.*, 'PLACEHOLDER')";

var query = '';
function registerShowRefsAlert(){

    var tagAdmin = CQ.tagging.TagAdmin,
        deleteTagFn = tagAdmin.deleteTag;

    //override ootb function to inject the logic showing references alert
    tagAdmin.deleteTag = function(){
        var tagPath = tagAdmin.getSelectedTag();

        if (tagPath == null) {
            return;
        }

        tagPath = tagPath.substring( this.tagsBasePath.length + 1);

        var tagInfo = CQ.tagging.parseTag(tagPath, true),
            query = encodeURIComponent(CHECK_TAGS_SQL_2_QUERY.replace("PLACEHOLDER", tagInfo.getTagID()));

        //you may want to replace this crxde lite call with a servlet returning query results
        query = "/crx/de/query.jsp?type=JCR-SQL2&showResults=true&stmt=" + query;

        //"this" here is tagadmin object, passed as context
        $.ajax( { url: query, context: this } ).done(showAlert);
    };

    function showAlert(data){
        console.log('query value' + query);
        if(_.isEmpty(data) || _.isEmpty(data.results)){
            deleteTagFn.call(this);
            return;
        }

        var message = "Selected tag is referenced. Click 'yes' to proceed deleting, 'no' to cancel the operation.<br><br>";

        _.each(data.results, function(result){
            message = message + result.path + "<br>";
        });

        CQ.Ext.Msg.show({
            "title": "Delete Tag",
            "msg": message,
            "buttons": CQ.Ext.Msg.YESNO,
            "icon": CQ.Ext.MessageBox.QUESTION,
            "fn": function (btnId) {
                if (btnId == "yes") {
                    this.postTagCommand("deleteTag", tagAdmin.getSelectedTag());
                    //Iterator<Resource> it = tag.find();
                    //console.log('the tag id' + it);
                    //this.deleteTag(it);
                }
            },
            "scope": this
        });
    }
}
```

}());

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVoCF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does eventually clear it up, it just does so in an asynchronous manner.

Take a scenario where you've added a tag to a page and then deleted it. If you then go into that page to look at the tags associated with it via a UI, that tag will not show up. However, if you go into CRX/DE you will still see it associated with a page.

If you perform a search via the TagManager API it will not find any pages associated with the deleted tag either.

The reason for this appears to have been a decision to have all the api's that interact with a tag resolve the tag when it's being requested. I'm sure this is to facilitate the situation where you are moving a tag or merging it into another tag.

There is a nightly job called com.day.cq.tagging.impl.TagGarbageCollector

That will go through and identify the tags and resolve them, which in your case will result in it being removed from the page.

Or to paraphrase, you don't need to do anything special, the tags will be updated nightly.

Comment: Sorry for late repy and thanks a lot. It worked fine.